Powershell extract custom line numbers using Get-Content
I have a file with 1000 lines, I want to extract only lines 250-500 (for example)
Using Get-Content, I already know how to do the following:

Extract the first X lines (head)  Get-Content -Path .\File1.txt -TotalCount 10
Extract the last X lines (tail)  Get-Item -Path .\File1.txt | Get-Content -Tail 1 -10
Extract a single, specific line  (Get-Content -Path .\File1.txt -TotalCount 10)[-1]

I assumed this would be rather straightforward, but I have searched and couldn't find an answer unfortunately.

--Tail -10 and Get-Content -Path .\File1.txt 10[-1] are not syntactically correct

@SantiagoSquarzon edited, thank you.

Why not just Get-Content File1.txt | Select-Object -Index (250..500)?

(Actually the range would be 249..499 because it's zero-based)

Get-Content wraps each string with a psobject instance and adds a .ReadCount property to that instance representing the "line number". You can, in this case, combine -TotalCount as the total lines to read (499 in the example, you need to substract 1) and then filter where .ReadCount is greater than or equal to 250.
Get-Content -Path .\File1.txt -TotalCount 499 | Where-Object ReadCount -GE 250

Another option is to use Select-Objet -Skip instead of Where-Object:
Get-Content -Path .\File1.txt -TotalCount 499 | Select-Object -Skip 249


seems to work, thanks
